# C# Redirect to about:blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redirect, .net-core

While using `RedirectResult Redirect(string url)` with "about:blank" it returns error that side cannot be reached and it loops infinitely inside my controller method

Can you please advice how could I handle about:blank case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect is basically done by using two declares on Headers - the url and the [status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#redirection_messages).

So the very basic of redirect is this two lines of code (for the "about:blank") where for security reasons is forbitten and response with `ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT`

```
Response.StatusCode = 301;
Response.RedirectLocation = "about:blank";
```

So this can not be done using redirect and header declarations.

There is a way around - use JavaScript and run this line

```
<script>window.location.href = 'about:blank';</script>
```

Alternative consider to create an empty page and redirect to this empty existing page - and avoid the `about:blank`